# QGIS Installation problem

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-10

Previously I had Windows 7 and I recently installed Windows 10 (64-bit) on my computer. Upon installation of QGIS ( newer /older versions) the installation completes taking more time than it usually did and when I open it, an error dialog box pops up. The error message is attached. It says re-installing may fix the problem but reinstalling didn't help.
[image]

Comment: This usually means that C++ runtime library is mising. Try installing: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: C++ runtimes are installed with qgis, but the install must be done with administrator rights. On Systems where a lot of programs have been installed before, chances are high, that the runtimes are already installed.

Comment: Please post error messages as ASCII text in the body of the question. This makes it legible on all devices and free-text searchable as well.

Comment: As you use Windows 10: take a look at c:\windows\System32 directory  and c:\windows\SysWOW64 directory. In each directory there should be a msvcr120.dll file. The System32 directory contains 64-bit dlls on a 64-bit Windows!! The SysWOW64 directory contains various files needed to run 32 bit programs on a 64-bit windows, so these two msvcr120.dll files are not the identical.